# Apache Rewrite Digital Asset Management files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How do I rewrite the Digital Asset Management files to *assetlinks.json*?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.well-known|apple-app-site-association) [NC]
RewriteRule assetlinks\.json [L]
```

I'm aware of what they are and know what I'm doing, I'm just having trouble with the rewrite.

---

Update; using:

```
RewriteRule ^.well-known/ assetlinks.json
```

The requested URL `.well-known/assetlinks.json` is correctly rewritten to `assetlinks.json`.

However the request URL `.well-known/apple-app-site-association` is not.

Comment: What is the full name of Digital Asset Management file?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Use this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/ assetlinks.json [NC,L]
```

Simplified to one rule, changed the matching logic a bit and removed `RewriteBase` that is not needed.

To go in root `.htaccess` file.

According to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html):

> Upload the apple-app-site-association file to your HTTPS web server.
>   You can place the file at the root of your server or in the
>   .well-known subdirectory.

So I went with that format, assuming that's what you want. Let me know if not.

Comment: It's a standard (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5785). I tried this at the top and bottom of the `.htaccess` file without luck. I tried both `.well-known/assetlinks.json` and `.well-known/assetlinks.json`.

Comment: Oh I see. This works the other way round! I'll change it.

Comment: I updated it so /assetlinks.json or /.well-known/assetlinks.json actually serves /apple-app-site-association

Comment: Okay, I think I need to clarify better: I need to rewrite to `public_root/assetlinks.json`. I don't want to create fifty different directories for various standards.

Comment: Good idea. Done if I understand what you want correctly. Let me know.

Comment: I just want to match any request to anything containing ".well-known" to "assetlinks.json" in the root public directory, it's not actually a directory named "public_root".

Comment: Well why didn't you say so :) all done, anything starting .well-known is rewritten to assetlinks.json

Comment: This works though only for the `assetlinks.json` file: `RewriteRule ^.well-known/ assetlinks.json`.

Comment: What do you mean? What do you want to match that isn't being?

Comment: Have you actually tried it? Both of those are rewritten with the rule provided. Please actually test things, rather than interpreting what is provided when you clearly don't know how to do that or you wouldn't be asking the question in the first place.